# Wordpress: Check posts have comments allowed

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page that displays certain posts from a certain category, in this case category 33 (Tutorials) and it currently outputs the title, post excerpt and permalink to the posts in this category:

```
<?php $top_query = new WP_Query('cat=33'); ?>
<?php while($top_query->have_posts()) : $top_query->the_post(); ?>
```

How Can I specify that the posts returned should only be ones that have comments enabled?. I have tried wrapping it in:

```
<?php if(comments_open()) : ?>
```

Hover that needs to be used within the loop :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/check-if-post-comment-is-enabled-or-not

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>
                   <?php if(comments_open()){ ?> 
                    <div class="news-row">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                        <div class="newsimagebox">
                          <?php //$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'thumbnail');
                              $images = the_post_thumbnail();?>
                           <?php echo $images;?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="news-content">
                    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>              
                    <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
                    <div class="readmore"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read More">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                   <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; //wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks